# POST http://localhost/MyApp/MyCon/customerCheck 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

config: $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myApp/';

I want check if the email already exists in the database or not. I have called a function(emailCheck()) onblur of a input field in registration form which is given as view in controller.

AJAX code:

```
function emailCheck(){
    var email = jQuery("#email").val();;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>myCon/customerCheck",
        data: {"email":email},
        success:function(response){
            if(response.status=="success"){
                 $('#test').html(response.message);
            } else {
                console.log(response.message)
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Controller code:

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  
    /**
    * 
    */
    class MyCon extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function customerCheck(){
            if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
                $this->load->model('CustomerModel');
                $mail = $this->input->post('email');
                $res = $this->customerModel->customerMailCheck($mail);
                if(!empty($res)) {
                    $data['status'] = 'success';
                    $data['message'] = 'Email Adress is found';
                } else {
                    $data['status'] = 'error';
                    $data['message'] = 'Data not found';

                }
                echo json_encode($data);
                exit;
            } else{
                redirect('somelink');
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Model code:

```
<?php
    class CustomerModel extends CI_Model{
        function __construct()
        {
            parent:: __construct();
        }
        function customerMailCheck($mail){
            $result = $this->db->get_where('privilege_customer', array('email' => $mail));
            return $result->result();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: check your logs.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  got these 2 errors
Undefined property: MyApp::$customerModel C:\wamp\www\myApp\application\controllers\MyApp.php &
Call to a member function customerMailCheck() on null

Comment: Well load call failed obviously. Seems off for CI naming conventions... `class Customer_model` and `->model('customer_model')` maybe?  Then use with  `$this->customer_model->foo()`

Comment: @ficuscr Thanks for the info. Problem solved.

Comment: OT: My eyes hurt, seeing `<?php echo ...` inside Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$res = $this->customerModel->customerMailCheck($mail);
```

if model name is case Sensitive then it should be

```
$res = $this->CustomerModel->customerMailCheck($mail);
```